# Angular *ngIf with concatenated string

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

i'm working with Angular 11, and i need to display and input type number based on a condition, the thing is i don't know how to properly pass the string to compare.

i have these dynamic tabs, the values of the inputs come from the database, i loop through the array and display the data, it's working so far, but i need to hide the input "precision" if its value is 0

[image]

this is the html part of the code

```
<div class="row ml-0 mr-0">
    <div class="col-6 " *ngFor="let item of dinamicData[tabz.title].data; let i = index">
        <div class="row ml-0 mr-0 mt-3" >
            <div class="col-6 float-center">
                 <label> {{ item.name }}</label>   
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row ml-0 mr-0 mt-3" >                    
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Dato</label>   
                <select #mySelect (change)="addCode(mySelect?.value, $event,tabz.title, item, i )" class="form-control" [formControlName]="tabz.title + '.' + item.name + '.name' ">
                    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Seleccione campo</option>
                    <option [value]="row?.name" *ngFor="let row of item?.template_header" >{{ row?.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <label>Tipo de dato</label>
                <select   class="form-control" [formControlName]="tabz.title + '.' + item.name + '.type'" (change)="onKey($event,tabz.title, item, i )">
                    <option [ngValue]="null" disabled>Seleccione tipo de dato</option>
                    <option [value]="row?.name" [id]="row.id" *ngFor="let row of DataType" >{{ row.name}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4" *ngIf="tabz.title + '.' + item.name + '.' + precision > 0" >
                <label>Precision</label>
                <input [formControlName]="tabz.title + '.' + item.name + '.precision'" min="0" type="number" class="form-control"  placeholder="Precici&oacute;n">
            </div>           
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the ts code where i populate the data

```
populateData( ) {
this.keys.forEach((value, key) =>{
  value.forEach((v, k) => {
    this.edit_conf_conciliation_form.setControl("Campo "+ (key+1)+".interfaz"+ (k+1)+".name", new FormControl(v.name))
    this.edit_conf_conciliation_form.setControl("Campo "+ (key+1)+".interfaz"+ (k+1)+".type", new FormControl(v.type))
    this.edit_conf_conciliation_form.setControl("Campo "+ (key+1)+".interfaz"+ (k+1)+".key", new FormControl(v.key))
    this.edit_conf_conciliation_form.setControl("Campo "+ (key+1)+".interfaz"+ (k+1)+".precision", new FormControl(v.precision))
    this.edit_conf_conciliation_form.setControl("Campo "+ (key+1)+".interfaz"+ (k+1)+".typeCode", new FormControl(v.typeCode))
    this.edit_conf_conciliation_form.setControl("Campo "+ (key+1)+".interfaz"+ (k+1)+".interfaceCode", new FormControl(v.interfaceCode))
  });
});
}
```

can this be done the way i'm thinking? i'm an angular noob, so any help will be appreciated.
greetings

Comment: so for example you need to compare `a.Texto.0 > 0` . What's the point on that? You compare a sentence with a number?

Comment: that's what i need to know man, i didnt know i wasn't even comparing the value of the formgroup, how can i compare the value?

Comment: please update the question and explain what your aim is. Make it more readable so we can help you out.

Comment: don't need to, already solved it when you said i wasn't comparing the value, with this expression, *ngIf="edit_conf_conciliation_form.controls[tabz.title + '.' + item.name + '.precision'].value > 0", thanks mate